# Blank Screen when fetching data from api

Tags: node.js, flutter, api, android-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I am fetching a data from `api` and display it in list using `ListView builder`, it's working properly on emulator but when I run app on my android phone it is displaying blank screen, here it looks.

[image]

below Leave History label, I am displaying data from api, but it looks like this now.

It looks like this on emulator

[image]

Here is the code:

**Fetching api data and inserting it into list**

```
List<leaveHistory> historyList = [];
var loader = 0;
Future<List<leaveHistory>> _getRecord() async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    var data = {
      'username': getname,
      'token': getaccesstoken,
    };

    return dio
        .post(localhostUrlLeaveHistoryON, data: json.encode(data))
        .then((onResponse) async {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = onResponse.data;
      List<dynamic> data = map["data"];

      for (var historyData in data) {
        leaveHistory history = leaveHistory(
            historyData["Date"],
            historyData["description"],
            historyData["type"],
            historyData['fromdate'],
            historyData["todate"],
            historyData["noofleavedays"],
            historyData["leave"]);
        historyList.add(history);
        loader = 0;
      }
      if (historyList.length == 0) {
        loader = 1;
      }
      return historyList;
    }).catchError((onerror) {
      loader = 1;
print(onerror.toString());
    });
  }
```

**display the data using ListView.builder**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new MyAppBar(
            title: Text("Leaves Tracker"),
            onpressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile()));
            }),
        drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
        body: Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible, children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 0),
            child: Text(
              "Leave History",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontFamily: 'RaleWay'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 0, 0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _getRecord(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<leaveHistory>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (historyList.length != 0) {
                      return Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
                          child: Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              Color c = Colors.red;
                              //changing the avatar color
                              if (i == 0)
                                i++;
                              else if (i == 1) {
                                c = Colors.blue;
                                i++;
                              } else if (i == 2) {
                                c = Color(int.parse(annualboxcolor));
                                i = 0;
                              }

                              Color c1 = Colors.green;
                              if (snapshot.data[index].Status == "Approved") {
                                c1 = Colors.green;
                              } else if (snapshot.data[index].Status ==
                                  "Not Approved") {
                                c1 = Colors.red;
                              } else if (snapshot.data[index].Status ==
                                  "Pending") {
                                c1 = Color(int.parse(pendingrequestcolor));
                              }
                              return SingleChildScrollView(
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      ListTile(
                                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 25,
                                              backgroundColor: c,
                                              child: Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                    0, 10, 0, 0),
                                                child:
                                                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                                                  Text(
                                                    snapshot
                                                        .data[index].noofdays
                                                        .toString(),
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                        color: Colors.white),
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    int.parse(snapshot
                                                                .data[index]
                                                                .noofdays) >
                                                            1
                                                        ? "Days"
                                                        : "Day",
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 10.0,
                                                        color: Colors.white),
                                                  )
                                                ]),
                                              )),
                                          title:
                                              Text(snapshot.data[index].type),
                                          isThreeLine: true,
                                          subtitle: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                snapshot.data[index].fromdate +
                                                    " To " +
                                                    snapshot.data[index].todate,
                                              ),
                                              Text(snapshot.data[index].Status,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: c1,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold)),
                                              Text(
                                                snapshot
                                                    .data[index].description,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                      Divider(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        height: 10,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ));
                            },
                          )));
                    }
                  }

                  if (loader == 1) {
                    print("run");
                    return Nodatafound();
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.blue[500],
                    ));
                  }
                }),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

**history class**

```
class leaveHistory {
  final String date;
  final String fromdate;
  final String todate;
  final String description;
  final String type;
  final String Status;
  final String noofdays;

  leaveHistory(this.date, this.description, this.type, this.fromdate,
      this.todate, this.noofdays, this.Status);
}
```

When i redirect to this screen from drawer it first display this error

```
DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [300]
```

on this `catchError` this line `print(onerror.toString());`

**Update:**

When i connect my phone with my laptop with datacable, it's working fine, but when i install `apk` problem occurs.

Please help where i am doing wrong.

Comment: are you set Internet Permission in android file?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by incorrect use of parent data widget. And that is from using expanded inside container. Remove your `Expanded` from here:

```
return Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
                          child: Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
```

You will also notice that the error in console is gone. Always read the errors and understand them. The error will 100% say, `incorrect use of parent widget`. Just remove the expanded.

Comment: i am still gettting the ```incorrect use of parent widget``` error and dio 300 error on emulator too,

Comment: PLease check my post Update part

Answer (score 0):

If @Huthaifa was not the answer you're looking, have you tried to update the value of: `localhostUrlLeaveHistoryON`?

If you're using something like: `http://localhost`

Please try to change this to your computer's ip address.

Comment: I doubt it's an internet issue or API related. It's also showing in release builds, because that's how errors appear in release, as grey areas instead of the usual red screen.

Comment: yeah that's why I put a disclaimer at first. But it's likely to be because of the catched error in dio.

Comment: Could be both actually.

Comment: yepyep, let's wait for his precious reply haha.

Comment: haha, both answers are not helping me! i am getting the api response data on my screen, my getting the 300 error too, i think at first when i redirect to screen it send me 300 error and too handle this i am display a circular loader, which is display when i redirect this screen and then after few seconds it display me data

Comment: but it is on emulator, it is not working on my phone!, i am using same network too on my laptop and phone.

Comment: May I ask what's the value of your variable: `localhostUrlLeaveHistoryON` when using your external phone?

Comment: how do you run it in your device? Is it a release version?

Comment: ```http://192.*.*.*:8000/leaveshistoryforempAll``` it is varible with a value this,

Comment: i am running this app on my phone using its apk.